# Confusing GPS coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gps

I'm reposting this question for the sake of clarity. I've been given a spreadsheet with coordinates that are in a variety of formats, all to be converted to DD for standardisation. I'm confused about a 6 digit format written simply 316146, as one example. That's all the coordinate info for that location.

The clarification I’ve received is that the 6 digit format is "decimal minutes south to 3 decimal places and decimal minutes east to 3 decimal places". Does this make sense to anyone? All coordinates fall within South Africa.

Relatively new to this but the 6 digit format has really confused me.